# 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' ERROR in my Tensorflow project

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

This is my Python Code:

```
print("train_x.shape", train_x.shape)
print("train_y.shape", train_y.shape)
print("Data type of train_x:", train_x.dtype)
print("Data type of train_y:", train_y.dtype)
print("Data type of train_y[0]:", train_y[0].dtype)


model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(train_x.shape[1],), name="Input"),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="linear", name="Entry"),
    keras.layers.Dense(train_y.shape[1], activation="linear", name="Output"),
    #keras.layers.Dense(train_y.shape[1], activation=None, name="Output"),
])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
print("Model input shape:", model.input_shape)
```

Output:

```
train_x.shape (22, 5000)
train_y.shape (22, 5000)
Data type of train_x: <dtype: 'float32'>
Data type of train_y: <dtype: 'float32'>
Data type of train_y[0]: <dtype: 'float32'>

Model: "sequential_3"

┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                       ┃ Output Shape                  ┃     Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ Entry (Dense)                      │ (None, 512)                   │   2,560,512 │
├────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ Output (Dense)                     │ (None, 5000)                  │   2,565,000 │
└────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘

 Total params: 5,125,512 (19.55 MB)

 Trainable params: 5,125,512 (19.55 MB)

 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)

None
Model input shape: (None, 5000)
```

When i run this, i get an error message:

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py:69, in TensorFlowTrainer.train_step(self, data)
     67 if self.trainable_weights:
     68     trainable_weights = self.trainable_weights
---> 69     gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_weights)
     71     # Update weights
     72     self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_weights))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'
```

The script uses audio segments as input and output, so that i can predict an audio sequence based on an input sequence.

I changed the activation functions and the compile settings but nothing worked.
And i dont know what the error message should tell me exactly.

Tensorflow version: 2.10.1
Keras version: 3.0.2

**EDIT**
It may not work because I updated some packages, simplified the code, and still get the error. Here's a full example code snippet causing the exact same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
print("Tensorflow version:", tf.__version__)
print("Keras version:", keras.__version__)

train_x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(train_x.shape[1],), name="Input"),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="linear", name="Entry"),
    keras.layers.Dense(train_x.shape[1], activation="linear", name="Output"),
])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
print("Model input shape:", model.input_shape)

model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_x, batch_size=2, epochs=10)
```

**Output**
Tensorflow version: 2.10.1
Keras version: 3.0.2

Model: "sequential"

┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                       ┃ Output Shape                  ┃     Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ Entry (Dense)                      │ (None, 512)                   │       2,048 │
├────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ Output (Dense)                     │ (None, 3)                     │       1,539 │
└────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘

Total params: 3,587 (14.01 KB)

Trainable params: 3,587 (14.01 KB)

Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)

None
Model input shape: (None, 3)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'

Comment: What are `train_x`and `train_y`? They should be numpy arrays or tensorflow tensors. Anything else (like pandas dataframe for example) would probably not work. See the doc: [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Lescurel thank you for your response!
<class 'list'> contains <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and is then converted to <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'> with tf.convert_to_tensor(..., dtype=tf.float32) or tf.constant(...).
Is this the issue?

Comment: I don't know. With the info you provide, the best we can do is guessing.

Comment: @Lescurel isn't base_dtype for Tensorflow Tensors?
When i run this Code:
test_tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
print("base_dtype:", test_tensor.base_dtype)
I get this error message:
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'

This error message is similar to the main error.

Comment: @Lescurel train_x.dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>
type(train_x): <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

Comment: @D.L I added a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issue!
I downgraded Keras to version 2.10.0.